# Temporarily including a sass file while compiling

Tags: ruby, windows, compilation, sass

All the sass files in my application are compiled into one big css file, but it's become rather bloated. In order to monitor where the bloat is coming from I've written a batch file to go through each individual sass file and compile it as a separate stylesheet. The problem is that each stylesheet is dependent on one in particular one - _mixins_and_vars.scss - which is only included once in my over-arching styles.scss stylesheet, and not referenced at all in the other sass files.

Is there a way I can temporarily import extra sass stylesheets while compilation is running?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion: in your batch script,

- insert reference to _mixins_and_vars.scss into your target file
- compile that
- remove reference
- PROFIT!

:-)

Comment: This is the approach I went for, but I'm no batch file guru so gave up in the end as adding a line then removing it after wasn't having the desired result, so I was doing something wrong, but coudln't see what.

Comment: You don't have to write such script in Bash, you can use Ruby, it's quite trivial there. :-)